# checking values in javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i check a value in javascript. for example:

```
document.formname.subcategory.options[0]=new Option("Select Sub-Category","");
document.formname.subcategory.options[1]=new Option("Colleges","Colleges");
document.formname.subcategory.options[2]=new Option("Institutes","Institutes");
document.formname.subcategory.options[3]=new Option("Schools","Schools");
document.formname.subcategory.options[4]=new Option("Tuitions","Tuitions");
document.formname.subcategory.options[5]=new Option("Universities","Universities");
```

how can i check the value if it's "Colleges" or "Schools", etc.? is it like this?

```
document.formname.subcategory.options.value == "Universities"
```

or like this?

```
document.formname.subcategory.options.value == 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one:

```
document.formname.subcategory.options.value == "Universities";
```

value is the string that will be sent to the server when the form is submitted, so you're comparing a string with a string. :D